# Angular 5 routing between child routes with/without ID

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have an Angular 5 app with a module with a routing configuration shown below

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'user/:userId',
        component: UserSelectionComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'overview',
            component: OverviewComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'selection',
            component: SelectionComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'selection/:groupId',
            component: SelectionComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

I have a save function in my SelectionComponent.ts which i want to route to the OverviewComponent when a save button is clicked.

```
this._router.navigate([`../overview`], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

This works OK when I navigate to selection without an ID.  However when I pass in an ID it routes from http://localhost:4200/user/1/selection/1 to http://localhost:4200/user/1/selection/overview rather than http://localhost:4200/user/1/overview

How can I use the same router.navigate code to navigate back from the SelectionComponent to the OverviewComponent whether on not an ID has been passed in?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `if/else` switch. Navigate to `../../overview` instead of `../overview` when the selection ID is defined.

Comment: I have that at the moment but was wondering if theres a cleaner way to do it